# Localize text on one page in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am learning asp.net MVC so I do not have so much experience.
I want to localize text on one page but I don’t want put labels to view model.
Too much text must be localized and it does not look right to put all text in view model properties.

I would like to read  localized value with razor directly from resource file.
Is this possible?
In what folder should I create resource file?
How should I name resource file?
How to read value at page from resource file?

Comment: If you use resource files (resx) just do it exactly as you would do it in your C# files. @Namespace.ResourceFileName.ResourceName. Everything else is up to you. See also [this article](http://adamyan.blogspot.it/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html).

Comment: I changed tags for your question: ASP.NET MVC is not ASP-CLASSIC. For usage examples see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25643388/1207195) (with links for more detailed resources).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not different from what you would do in plain C# code. A detailed description (even if it's not about Razor same concepts still apply) can be found in [this article](http://adamyan.blogspot.it/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html).

First of all you have to decide where you want to put your resource files. Elective place is **Resources** folder. Alex suggests (and it's pretty reasonable) to mimic solution structure (views, model and controllers) there to keep things organized and tidy. In practice you'll have a structure like this:

```
.
   /Resources
       /Models
           LogInModel.resx
       /Controllers
           LogIn.resx
       /Views
           /Home
               LogIn.resx
               Index.resx
```

and so on. Localized resources will be simply used like this:

**Views**

```
<head>
    <title>@MyProject.Resources.Views.Home.Index.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>@MyProject.Resources.Views.Home.Index.Welcome</h1>
</body>
```

**Models**

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", 
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyProject.Resources.Models.LogIn))]
[ValidatePasswordLength(ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordMinLength", 
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyProject.Resources.Models.LogIn))]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[DisplayName("Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

**Controllers**

```
var user = FindUserByName(userName);
if (user == User.Nobody)
    ModelState.AddModelError("1", MyProject.Resources.Controllers.Search.UserNotFound);
```

Now let's enable localization (which may be different for each thread then for its request). This is just an example, please refer to full article for all details:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
    {
        string name = (CultureInfo)this.Session["Culture"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(name );
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
                CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

### References

- [Internationalization and localization in MVC 5](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx).
- [Globalization, Internationalization and Localization in ASP.NET MVC 3, JavaScript and jQuery](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx).
- [ASP.NET MVC Localization complete guide](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html).

Comment: I create resource, and I have on page :<label>@MyProject.Resources.Views.Home.Study.lblTitle</label>.
But I get exception:
An exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "MyProject.Resources.Views.Home.Study.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "MyProject" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Comment: @merso0027 _Probably_ you just need to regenerate your resource files (double click on .resx file, make sure code generation is active and visibility is **public**) then close it. Code generator will run and you'll have your resources. Also note that namespace must match with what you actually have in your project (replace MyProject.Resources with right namespace, IntelliSense will help you on this).