# Set/Change/Update current culture dynamically c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

**I am trying to change the current culture in web api throuch c#.net. I've tried in web forms and asp.net mvc also, but didn't work**

After I go through some answers from Stack overflow, I've found the following answer to change the current culture.

```
  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Code);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Code);
```

But after I update, the culture has been changed for the current request only. After sending another request from the application, the culture info has been changed to default one.

**I don't know what's happening. I want to maintain the current culture for the application till the user log out**.

How to implement this one?

Comment: You need to do this in the global.asax file, if you are in a asp.net mvc/web forms application. If you are in a web-api, I think it does not make sense, since in a web-api project you have no application, rather just independent http requests

Comment: Thank you. If we are using asp.net mvc/web forms application, How to do in global.asax?

Comment: I've tried in asp.net MVC/web forms application too, but didn't work.. How to implement in global.asax?

Comment: It's working exactly as it should: what happens when 2 users with different culture log in?? You want culture to depend on a each user and be parametric for each request; I think.

Comment: related: [Localize text on one page in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25643017/1207195). You may skip stuff about localization with MVC and jump directly to paragraph about how to set culture for thread of served request.

Answer (score 1):

You can override Application_BeginRequest in your Global.asax file to change the culture on each request.

Edit: Technically not an override. More here: [how do you wire up Application_BeginRequest() in asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590578/how-do-you-wire-up-application-beginrequest-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: See edit. There's some sample code and explanations there.

Comment: I had confused. You are saying to change the culture on each request. Right? I did translate on button click. Shouldn't this retain on all the request?

Comment: No, you have to [change it for each request](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25643017/1207195). Same thread may be reused for multiple requests (made by different users). Your next request may be in another thread or even in another process.